# Open multiple hyperlinks (and only those) in column after filtering data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have a database with about 260 rows. After filtering using "auto-filter" I need only remaining and visible hyperlinks to open. All hyperlinks are local and not on the Internet.

I have searched the Internet and have not found a working answer. This question is even posed here in "Stackoverflow" and the response did not provide a solution.

I have used:

```
Sub OpenHyperLinks()
    Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "OpenHyperlinksInExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
        xHyperlink.Follow
    Next
End Sub
```

This opens ALL the hyperlinks, not just the ones remaining after filtering. I have over 200 hyperlinks and after filtering using "auto-filter" I need the links that remain visible to open and only those links. These hyperlinks are local and not Internet.

Comment: Try `For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Hyperlinks`.

Comment: This is the edit I made based on your answer. The result was the same. It opened all the hyperlinks in the column not just those that were visible after auto-filter. Thank you for your effort. Any more ideas?

Comment: Reference the range like I posted in the previous comment: `Dim rg As Range. Set rg = WorkRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`. Now turn off the filter `rg.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False` and continue per the program except for `... In rg.Hyperlinks`.

Comment: I will give it a try. A try is all I can do. I am not a programmer. It would be more useful if I could get the macro or code from start to END Sub. Otherwise, a try is all I can do. I know how to search the Internet and I have seen this exact question posed twice with no functional resolution. I am sure it might work for you if you pop that into your code, but what I am going to do.. try. I don't have high expectations. Any chance I can get the full script?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but it also doesn't work in the way I proposed.

Comment: Is this the end? What I have done was move filtered results to another sheet then use macro to open hyperlinks in the row. It just seems so .. added/unnecessary step.